# Anyone receive an email about a free t-shirt?

Tags: discussion, t-shirt

Just received an email for a free superuser t-shirts, along with a form to fill out. Is this legit?

Comment: superuser is for computer hardware and software questions **only**. This question is more appropriately asked on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Congrats on hitting 3k with my upvote though. :)

Comment: congrats.  this will be migrated now.  :)

Comment: ... I read the last word as *legal*. :(

Comment: Did I just double upvote? Did my upvote from superuser carry over and then I was able to upvote the question again?

Comment: I'd say they are giving free T-shirts to the first 2 pages of each site, or something like that.

Comment: @Josh: yes. yes, you did.

Comment: Quickly! Migrate it to Server Fault.

Comment: @quack: Cool... :)

Comment: @Sam: Why serverfault?

Comment: So you can achieve a triple upvote.

Comment: I also want that T-Shirt. If I could buy it, I want to buy it.. I've a serious desire :(

Comment: @mgpyone You can buy them now.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/t-shirt-time-beta

Comment: thx in advanced. justin :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is perfectly **legit**.

Comment: Mine arrived yesterday.

Comment: how do we get a tshirt?

Comment: @studiohack Buy one?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/t-shirt-time-beta

Comment: I just provided my mailing address - guess it'll take another couple of weeks to reach.

Comment: @Justin GET ONE FREE! THIS LOVELY SUPER USER T-SHIRT COULD BE YOURS FOR JUST $11.99!! YOU'LL ALSO RECEIVE THIS COMPLEMENTARY WAFFLE, SPRINKLED WITH UNICORN DUST!!! **BUT THAT'S NOT ALL!!!!** ORDER WITHIN THE NEXT HOUR AND YOU COULD ALSO RECEIVE THIS LOVELY UNICORN AVATAR **FREE OF CHARGE**!!!!!

Comment: How do you know that this particular mail is legit? A naughty person might send additional e-mails to harvest s-mail addresses for the purposes of stealing ur waffles.