# Super Contest Winners: Week 2

Tags: discussion, super-contest

This post is to document the **week 2** winners of the [Super User Super Contest](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/19/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/), for the week ending **Monday, September 6**.

Congratulations to our winners this week!

1. [Best rookie](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-08-30) performance by [**Shogun**](https://superuser.com/users/48219/cloudmeta) and [**pattern86**](https://superuser.com/users/48154/jsejcksn)

   [image: best rookie performance week of 08-30-2010]

   (special exception this week, since both new users were worthy -- both get the prize!)
2. [Highest reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2010-08-30) produced by [**KronoS**](https://superuser.com/users/47225/james-mertz)

   [image: top users week of 08-30-2010]

3. Best meta post:

   [New Users—Cutting Slack?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1350/new-users-cutting-slack/1351#1351) answer by [**DMA57361**](https://meta.superuser.com/users/39366/dma57361)
4. Most awesome new question or answer:

   [tool to find out which video card is installed on my system?](https://superuser.com/questions/184803/tool-to-find-out-which-video-card-is-installed-on-my-system/184804#184804) answer by [**Wil**](https://superuser.com/users/4386/william-hilsum)

We are contacting the winners now, so be sure to check your email inboxes!

Comment: On to week three!

Comment: Woohoo Congrats to all!!

Answer (score 7):

I accidentally plugged my mouse in wrong, and won a contest: [I accidentally plugged my USB mouse into my eSata port... it works?](https://superuser.com/questions/183543/i-accidentally-plugged-my-usb-mouse-into-my-esata-port-it-works) Cool right? Thanks SuperUser!

Comment: X users now accidentally fry their motherboard to win the next week.

Comment: @TomWij Or their esata disks while being at it...

Comment: Hey thanks for asking that... it helped me out too :)

Comment: Well don't shy away from asking any questions that are not related to sticking cables in places they might not belong!

Comment: Does this mean i can ask why i can't connect to the internet by connecting my phone line to the NIC?

Answer (score 5):

Congrats to the winners :D

[image: close]

Comment: Isn't this answer an exact duplicate of http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1342/super-contest-winners-week-1/1346#1346

Comment: Where is the close button? :-(

Comment: @DMA Yup it is ;) expect the same exact dupe for another 2 weeks :P

Comment: @DMA5 Voted as closed ;)

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was too funny to not share with everyone...

My t-shirt and stickers have arrived (thanks btw!). Along with an *interesting* post-it note:
[image: Stack Exchange stickers with interesting post-it note]

And here's a close-up:
[image: Interesting post-it note close up]

It's a proper post-it type note as well, with a little sticky across the top of the back. The ink has seeped through it a little. Nothing else in here to explain why it's there, just shows the humour of the SE team, I guess, which is great.

I think I shall make it my gravatar, at least for a while. :)

Comment: hehe, I got the same post-it too.

Comment: How random... lol

Comment: @Sathya - hold on, I've just spotting you've not won any of the prizes so far from this competition - so was yours from a previous one? Is this a long-running thing then?

Comment: @DMA5 - It was a one-time thing [They had sent a T-shirts](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/936/anyone-receive-an-email-about-a-free-t-shirt) to all folks listed in the first page of [/users](http://superuser.com/users) - and - I was [amongst the last](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1155/im-losing-my-hope-for-my-superuser-t-shirt) persons to [get the T-shirt](http://post.sathyabh.at/got-my-stack-overflow-super-user-t-shirt-stic)

Comment: We've had quite a few giveaways :) not that I won any of 'em :( but giveaways have always been there

Comment: @DMA57361 - I got a very similar post-it with my shirt today!

Answer (score 2):

First time I saw [DMA57361](https://meta.superuser.com/users/39366/dma57361) gravatar I thought: *ok, I'm crazy*.

[image]